Stop output from Android emulator in terminal so next command can be executed
The below script is used to open an Android emulator and install an react native app on it. I would like to hide the output of the emulator in the terminal so the next command can be read instead of the output of the emulator. How can I do that?
read -p "Which Android emulator name (i.e. Pixel_7_Pro_API_34)?: " device

emulator -avd $device &
adb wait-for-device shell 'while [[ -z $(getprop sys.boot_completed) ]]; do sleep 1; done; input keyevent 82'
npx react-native run-android


hi, terminals like Alacritty has a flag that lets you do this (for eg: alacritty -e emulator -avd $device). but, it seems like the integrated terminal from VS code can't do this. btw, if you just want to hide the emulator's output, you can redirect the output to /dev/null like this: emulator -avd $device &> /dev/null.

That actually should be an alternative on what I need.

If you provided your answer to my question, which I updated in the title then Ill mark it as answered as it works!

Mike!
this can be achieved by redirecting the output of the command to /dev/null by using:
emulator -avd $device &> /dev/null
explanation: 1> /dev/null redirects stdout to /dev/null and 2> /dev/null redirects stderr to /dev/null. using &> /dev/null redirects both. 1 is stdout. 2 is stderr.
PS: you can also use 2>& 1 to to redirect stderr to stdout.
